# Windows Error [5] : Access Denied H2o Deep Learning Framework Initialization using Python

Tags: python, r, windows, initialization, h2o

I'm using Windows 10, Anaconda 2.4.1, and Python 2.7.11 and trying to run the h2o package from oxdata.

To install h2o, I had used:

```
pip install h2o
```

I'm trying to initialize it as given in the Python Vignette of H2o package.

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
```

But I'm getting a long traceback mentioning Windows Error [5] as follows:

```
    No instance found at ip and port: localhost:54321. Trying to start local jar...


JVM stdout: c:\users\ashish\appdata\local\temp\tmpech694\h2o_Ashish_started_from_python.out
JVM stderr: c:\users\ashish\appdata\local\temp\tmp7aoeza\h2o_Ashish_started_from_python.err
Using ice_root: c:\users\ashish\appdata\local\temp\tmpjijmdl

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-e7cfdc50af66>", line 1, in <module>
    h2o.init()

  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\h2o.py", line 668, in init
    H2OConnection(ip=ip, port=port,start_h2o=start_h2o,enable_assertions=enable_assertions,license=license,max_mem_size_GB=max_mem_size_GB,min_mem_size_GB=min_mem_size_GB,ice_root=ice_root,strict_version_check=strict_version_check)

  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 81, in __init__
    cld = self._start_local_h2o_jar(max_mem_size_GB, min_mem_size_GB, enable_assertions, license, ice_root, jar_path)

  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\connection.py", line 181, in _start_local_h2o_jar
    jver = subprocess.check_output([command, "-version"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Users\Ashish\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

But if I install h2o package in R language using

```
install.packages("h2o")
```

and then try to run in R

```
library(h2o)
h <- h2o.init()
```

There is no error and h2o starts perfectly on localhost and port 54321.

Also, now if start h2o in python, i.e. in python

```
h2o.init()
```

Then it connects to the already running instance of h2o and performs all the operations without any problem.

But I want to avoid the step of pre-starting h2o instance and want to start it with python. I don't know whether my problem is reproducible on somebody else's system.

I simply want to use

```
import h2o
h2o.init()
```

to start h2o in python.

Please try to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to solve my problem using the following code.

```
"""
Code to initialize H2O instance

@author: Naimish Agarwal
"""

import subprocess as sp
import sys
import os.path as p
import h2o

# path of h2o jar file
h2o_path = p.join(sys.prefix, "h2o_jar", "h2o.jar")

# subprocess to launch h2o
# the command can be further modified to include virtual machine parameters
sp.Popen("java -jar " + h2o_path)

# h2o.init() call to verify that h2o launch is successfull
h2o.init()
```

And it produced the following output:

```
--------------------------  --------------------------
H2O cluster uptime:         2 seconds 603 milliseconds
H2O cluster version:        3.6.0.8
H2O cluster name:           Ashish
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster total memory:   3.54 GB
H2O cluster total cores:    4
H2O cluster allowed cores:  4
H2O cluster healthy:        True
H2O Connection ip:          127.0.0.1
H2O Connection port:        54321
--------------------------  --------------------------
```